# How to change the angle of the the axis in the unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[image: Please check this image]

How can i put that upper cube to the every top of the vertical cube ? how to set that horizontal top cube to around 27deg angle??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question. If you just need to rotate the cube: you can use `Rotate(float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);`
so for example `cube1.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 27.0f, Space.Self);`